# Where can I get a driver for the create2?

Tags: driver

I just bought a create2 and wanted to connect it with my laptop. Unfortunatly my laptop is not able to recognice the create2. I suppose I need a driver to solve this. Does anyone know where a fitting driver is to download?
Thank you

Comment: where have you looked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say what operating system your laptop runs, so I'll assume Windows.

I suspect you need a USB-to-UART bridge driver. The one I use (albeit for an ESP32) was downloaded from Silicon Labs.
https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers

Once Windows itself recognizes the device, a COM port will get assigned. Mine always gets COM3. Also your software and your device need to agree on the classic UART parameters, most importantly speed (like 115200).

Good luck! I hope it works as well for Create2 as for ESP32.